# MongoDB: using $map to update objects in query pipeline

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a list of objects returned from a call to `db.collection.aggregate()` that returns an array of result objects that look like this:

```
{ _id: <some_id>,
  count: 400,
  results:
   [ 
     { _id: 1,
       ...
       travel_guess: 0.1934042214126773,
     },
     { _id: 2,
       <>
       ...
       travel_guess: 0.8451461966883353,
     },
     ...
}
```

where `travel_guess` is a field added by mongoDB's `$geoNear` query pipeline function. I'm trying to update `travel_guess` to `ceil(travel_guess)` with a `$map` in my query pipeline:

```
$project: {
    _id: <some_id>,
    count: '$count',
    results: {
        $map: {
          input: '$results',
          as: 'result',
          in: {
            'travel': { $ceil: '$$result.travel_guess' }
          }
        },
    },
  }
},
```

While this successfully updates `travel_guess`, all other fields are removed, so I end up with an object like this:

```
{ _id: <some_id>,
  total: 400,
  results:
   [ { travel: 1 },
     { travel: 1 },
     { travel: 1 },
     { travel: 1 },
     { travel: 2 },
     { travel: 2 },
     { travel: 3 },
     ...
   ]
}
```

How can I persist the other fields in my result objects? Unfortunately, I'm constrained to using MongoDB version 3.4, so I'm limited in what query pipeline functions I can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify each field inside the `in` expression. Something like

```
{ "$project": {
  "_id": 1,
  "count": "$count",
  "results": {
    "$map": {
      "input": "$results",
      "as": "result",
      "in": {
        "travel": { "$ceil": "$$result.travel_guess" },
        "_id": "$$result._id",
        "otherField": "$$result.otherField"
      }
    }
  }
}}
```

And If you don't want to point each field inside `$map`

```
{ "$project": {
  "_id": 1,
  "count": "$count",
  "results": {
    "$map": {
      "input": "$results",
      "as": "result",
      "in": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$$result",
          { "travel": { "$ceil": "$$result.travel_guess" }}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}}
```

Comment: Awesome! That seems to work. But the result objects are quite complex, they each have ~35 fields where some are nested objects etc. Is there a way to target every field in the current object at once?

Comment: Yes there is a way but for that you have to update your mongodb version. Can yo do?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not something I have control over. It might be updated at a later time though. What was the solution you were thinking of?

Comment: @Sam Updated my answer. But it is only for 3.6 and above.